# Can I see the result of any update on my Sass files without runing rake assets:precompile?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sass, assets, development-environment

I'm using Rails 3.2.21 , SASS-rails and HAML-rails.

Each time I modify a sass stylesheet, the changes does not show on my web page until I run a `rake assets:precompile`.

This is pretty annoying in development mode.

Is there any mean to make rails read the sass directly in development mode ? or any other mean to ease my life ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In devel mode, rails should auto precompile your sass files.

You should search your project files to check whether you have setted assets.compile to false.

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#live-compilation

Comment: Shouldn't it be the opposite ? The guide says : In some circumstances you may wish to use live compilation. In this mode all requests for assets in the pipeline are handled by Sprockets directly. config.assets.compile = true

Comment: Where does it goes ? in config/environments/development.rb or in config/application.rb ?

Comment: Great ! I added config.assets.compile = true in my config/environments/devlopment.rb and it did the trick ! It sees my rails 3.2 was taking by default config.assets.compile = false. Why ? Coudl it be because config.assets.enabled = true in my config/application.rb ?